# Cannot sent message to ibm mq after building the jar

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mq

1)When I run the app in idea it works.

```
public class Sender {
  private MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
  private MQQueueConnection connection = null;
  private MQQueueSession session = null;
  private Queue queue = null;
  private MQQueueSender sender = null;
  private TextMessage message = null;

  public void send(String msg) throws JMSException {
    cf.setHostName("host");
    cf.setPort(port);
    cf.setQueueManager("manager");
    cf.setChannel("channel");
    cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection("user", "pswrd");
    session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queue = session.createQueue("queue");
    sender =  (MQQueueSender)session.createSender(queue);
    message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
    sender.send(message);
    session.commit();
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

2)I added all libraries

```
com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.4.jar
jms-1.1.jar
ibm.mq.jmqi-7.5.0.4.jar
com.ibm.mq.headers-7.5.0.4.jar
com.ibm.disthub2-7.5.0.4.jar
```

EDIT

[image]

to my local maven repo like this

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jms-1.1.jar -DgroupId=com.ibm.jms -DartifactId=evkuzmin-jms -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then added them to the project as dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>evkuzmin-jms</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3)I build using maven-assembly-plugin a jar with dependencies.

This is the error I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: null

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: JMSCMQ0001, 2, MQCC_FAILED, 2195, MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'host(port)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2195],3=host(port),5=WMQThreadPool.enqueue]

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195

Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002
```

Why does it fail after packaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2)I added all libraries

That's not all of the required MQ libraries.  These are the required MQ JAR files:

- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms.jar
- connector.jar
- jms.jar
- jndi.jar

Why don't you use MQ V8 Client and then simply use the MQ JAR file called:  com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar

Comment: MQ V8 Client needs to be installed right? The problem is I need to run the app on a server without mq to send send message to another server with mq. I don't have pesmission to install anything on the first one. I'll try to add dependencies for all jars I have.

Comment: You were right. I had to add all jars. Still don't understand why it worked without those jars before packaging. I added an image with all libs I have. Could the new error be because I am still missing a library?

Comment: @Evgenii Just google MQ v8 redistributable client, this is just a self extracting jar file, no administrative permissions are required to extract the jar files from this.

Comment: adding allclient helped. Though I also needed a couple of spring dependencies. Like here https://github.com/lzp4ever/IBM_WebSphere_MQ_Spring_Boot_JMS/blob/master/pom.xml