# MQRC '2195' ('MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR') with Tomcat 9 and MQ libs8 from Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat, ibm-mq

We are facing an issue running an application on Tomcat 9 (Java8). The application team has download the jar files on maven (v8.0.0.5), the queue manager in running on V9.0.0.5: When the application try to connects it gets the following error.

```
thread #10 - JmsConsumer[DLQ.FXOResponse] - ] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Initiating transaction rollback on listener exception com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'DLQ.queueName'. at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:213) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at ....org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132) ~[spring-jms-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE] at ...java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172] Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2195' ('MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR'). at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] ... 19 more

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1296) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:309) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:259) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:221) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.(LocalMQ.java:1350) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2] at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.(LocalServer.java:230) ~[com.ibm.mq.jmqi-8.0.0.5.jar:8.0.0.5 - p800-005-160516.2]
```

I have used a MQ Client v9 installed in another machine, FULL MQ Client package and managed to connect normally.

Comment: What are the 19 more lines of the stack?   Why don't you use a more up to date version,  8.0.0.12 for example?

Comment: Are there any FDCs or error messages on the queue manager?

Comment: Also note the 2495 can been ignored, this is normal for Java/JMS app that is not running on the same server as a queue manager.

Comment: @Josh the application team said they have tried versions v8.0.0.12 and v9.0.5.0, but all with the same output.

Comment: @Morag unfortunately that is not generating any FDC, that is really strange. I gave them this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159091/cannot-sent-message-to-ibm-mq-after-building-the-jar). But they say they are using the binaries like is mentioned in there. And all IBM provided by Maven.

Comment: Two things I think is strange. 1 - If I use the full MQClient installation it works. 2 - They say that only happens to some, not all, backout queues.

Comment: What permission do they have on the app queue and associated backout queue?

Comment: Also on the queue manager object.

Comment: I've seen this error when connecting to a local QM in bindings mode using the full MQ client JAR. The solution was to set up the LIBPATH environment variable to point at the Java lib dir of the local MQ installation e.g. /usr/mqm/java/lib64. I think setting up the environment using the setmqenv or setting the default installation to the full MQ install should also help.

Comment: Hello Josh, Morag and Atilla. It was what were were thinking here, during the application migration they needed to re-write the code in order to use the correct libraries. They didn’t give much information. But as thought it was needed some coding at app side Thanks you all